# Swift limit user action at once. (Disable an action)

Tags: swift, action, limit

i'm working on an app in Swift, one of the action is when the user tap a button the label change to 1 if he press again the value change to 2, etc..

I'm looking to disable the user to press again the button afther first time, it's in a tableview and i need the app keep in memory if the user press the button or not ( even if the app is closed ).
Does you guys have an idea? Here's my code:

```
@IBAction func likesButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

    var query = PFQuery(className: "Posts")
    query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(object.objectId, block: { (obj:PFObject!, error:NSError!) -> Void in

        if error != nil{
            println("Erreur \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }else{

            var likesNumber = obj.objectForKey("Likes")[0] as Int
            obj["Likes"] = [likesNumber + 1]
            self.likesButton.setTitle("\(likesNumber + 1) Participants", forState: UIControlState.Normal)

            obj.save()
        }

    })

}
```

Hope you could help me!
Have a nice day guys :)

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code...
 am sure it will help
@IBAction func likesButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

```
var query = PFQuery(className: "Posts")
query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(object.objectId, block: { (obj:PFObject!, error:NSError!) -> Void in

    if error != nil{
        println("Erreur \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }else{
        if obj["Likes"] == 0{
        var likesNumber = obj.objectForKey("Likes")[0] as Int
        obj["Likes"] = [likesNumber + 1]
        self.likesButton.setTitle("\(likesNumber + 1) Participants", forState: UIControlState.Normal)

        obj.save()
     }
    }

})
```

}

Comment: Doesn't work.. the value don't change anymore, maybe i forgot to add i'm using a Parse server to count the number of likes?

Comment: can you get the number of likes on the parse server?

Comment: Yes the server count the number of likes in the column "Like" and i'd like to display all the user who pressed this button on this post in this category, but i'd like to limit the number at one per user (no repetition) .. no idea .. :(